# Subtract a list of keyvalue by another list of keyvalue

Tags: c#, list, linq

is there a way of doing thing through linq without having to do a nested for loop and checking the key (i.e below)

**Assumptions** : each list doesn't contain *duplicate dates*

```
foreach(KeyValuePair value1 in List1)
{
   foreach(KeyValuePair value2 in List2)
   {
        if(value1.Key == Value2.Key)
        {
            .........
        }
        else
        {
           ......
        }
   }
}
```

I have two lists

**List1**

```
DateTime, Value
2017/01/01, 5
2017/01/02, 10
2017/01/05, 15
```

**List2**

```
DateTime, Value
2017/01/01, 1
2017/01/03, 3
2017/01/04, 5
```

the **Outcome** needs to be (list 1 - list 2)

```
DateTime, Value
2017/01/01, 4
2017/01/02, 10
2017/01/03, -3
2017/01/04, -5
2017/01/05, 15
```

Comment: Why dont you use `KeyValuePair`?

Comment: it is, i just manually typed it in the thread, so missed it when i posted

Comment: If the first list contains duplicate dates you want to sum those values too?

Comment: hi, there are no duplicated dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to subtract `list2` from `list1` (i.e. add up `list1` and *negated* `list2`):

```
   var result = list1
     .Concat(list2
        .Select(pair => new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(pair.Key, -pair.Value)))
     .GroupBy(pair => pair.Key, 
              pair => pair.Value)
     .Select(chunk => new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(chunk.Key, chunk.Sum()))
     .OrderBy(pair => pair.Key);
```

Comment: Hi, this works great and to change from sub to multiply was a simple change by keeping list1 positive and instead of chunk.sum() i did a chunk.Aggregate((e1, e2) => e1 * e2)

Comment: @UndeadEmo: quite right:  `Concat` (with possible modification - negation in the code above), `GroupBy` and `Aggregate` (`Sum` or custom one).

Comment: Though a ridiculous edge case if `pair.Value` in list2 is `int.MinValue` then this code will overflow when you do `-pair.Value`. I doubt this is going to be relevant ever but I always think of this edge case whenever I see `-` used as the unary operator.

Comment: @Chris: Nice catch! If there's possibility of *overflow*, casting to `long` will help: `list1.Select(pair => new KeyValue<DateTime, long>(pair.Key, pair.Value)).Concat(..new KeyValuePair<DateTime, long>(pair.Key, -(long)pair.Value)))....Select(chunk => new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(chunk.Key, (int)chunk.Sum()));`

Answer (score 1):

I think, in your case you can use a simply `loop` instead of `Linq`. Also, it will be not a nested one as you mentioned;

```
        var listA = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(new DateTime(2017,01,01),15),
            new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(new DateTime(2017,01,02),15),
            new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(new DateTime(2017, 01, 04), 15),
            new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(new DateTime(2017, 01, 05), 15)
        };
        var listB = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(new DateTime(2017, 01, 01), 10),
            new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(new DateTime(2017, 01, 03), 15)
        };
        var listC = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>();
        var maxCount = Math.Max(listA.Count, listB.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++)
        {
            if (listA.Count < i + 1)
            {
                listC.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(listB[i].Key,-listB[i].Value));
                continue;
            }
            if (listB.Count < i + 1)
            {
                listC.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(listA[i].Key, listA[i].Value));
                continue;
            }
            if (listA[i].Key == listB[i].Key)
            {
                int value = listA[i].Value - listB[i].Value;
                listC.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(listA[i].Key, value));
            }
            else
            {
                listC.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(listA[i].Key, listA[i].Value));
                listC.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(listB[i].Key, -listB[i].Value));
            }
        }
```